# Do the ternary Condition true after every 9 times looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to true a condition if loop is every 9 times, means first time it will be 9 second time it will we 18 third time it will be 27 when condition will meet (9,18,27 further) then do the condition true else do the condition false

here is ternary Condition

```
(i == count ? j++ : j)
```

here is code

```
var count = 9;
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {                        
    var output = '<ul class="selection page-' + (i == count ? j++ : j) + '">';
    output += '<li >';
    output += '<table><tr>';
    output += '<td><img src="http://localhost:37245/NewPeaceAuto - Steer_Well/WebStock_Images/' + data.d[i].Image1 + '" alt=""/></td>';
    output += '<td>CHASSIS NO:</td><td>' + data.d[i].CHASSIS_NO + '</td>';
    output += '<td>MODEL:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MODEL + '</td>';
    output += '<td>COLOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].color + '</td>';
    output += '<td>TRANS:</td><td>' + data.d[i].TRANSMISSION + '</td>';
    output += '<td>DOOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].DOOR + '</td>';
    output += '<td>MAKE:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MAKE + '</td>';
    output += '</tr></table></li></ul>';
    $("#update").append(output);

    count = count + 9;                        

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove count and use

`i % 9 == 8` instead of `i == count`

this will trigger every 9th time starting on the 9th time.

(while you could do `(i + 1) % 9 == 0` this gives the same results but is slightly more performant, due to the lack of needing to add 1)

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    if((i + 1) % 9 == 0){
        //Is exactly divisible by 9
    }
    else{
        //Is not exactly divisible by 9
    }
}
```

You can use the `%` [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
((i+1) % 9 ? j++ : j)
```